# Batch file's for loop options return ECHO is on instead of proper results

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I'm writing a batch file that should search through multiple folders and return the folder names and all files that are inside.

Here's the basic code for that script:

```
@echo off
cd c:\

dir /b /s C:\Path\to\the\destiation | for /f "delims=\; tokens=3,4,5*" %%a in ('findstr Folder1\') do @echo %%b: %%d >> file.txt
```

This produces a text flie "file.txt" that looks like this:

```
FolderName1: File1.ext
FolderName1: File2.ext
FolderName2: File3.ext
```

I also need to be able to add the file size and the "last modified" information from windows explorer.

I read through the information with `help for` and realized I should be able to use `%%~td` and `%%~zd`. So barring any formatting issues in the text file, to get this information printed into the text file, I tried using this:

```
dir /b /s C:\Path\to\the\destiation | for /f "delims=\; tokens=3,4,5*" %%a in ('findstr Folder1\') do @echo %%~td >> file.txt

dir /b /s C:\Path\to\the\destiation | for /f "delims=\; tokens=3,4,5*" %%a in ('findstr Folder1\') do @echo %%~zd >> file.txt
```

but those two loops only return this: `ECHO is on.`

Obviously I've missed something but I don't understand why these don't work. When I give the for loop a specific destination and use these options, it works perfectly on a single file.

I've tried googling things like "For loop options produce 'ECHO on'" but I'm getting no good results.

Comment: Please post unedited code. Your current code will not be parsed. The classic reason for the error message you are getting is that the thing to be echoed is empty. Possibly also post a small sample of the result of your `dir` command - and what you expect as output.

Comment: I am baffled by this: `for /for`

Comment: My exact code is exactly there except that I have a pause at the end. I'm showing you a test script to try and solve the problem. The problem is isolated to this section of the code.

Comment: Never seen anybody pipe output to a for loop before. I can't imagine that would possibly work.

Comment: There are missing doublequotes just after tokens declaration. You may enclose Folder1\ string with doublequotes too.

Comment: I checked and the missing double quotes is another typo. I'm having to type out the code because its on another computer. I corrected it.

Also, why wouldn't these for loops work? They do work just not with the options added.

Comment: Oh, _wow_ that's weird. Normal syntax would be `for /f "delims=\; tokens=3,4,5*" %%a in ('dir /b /s C:\Path\to\the\destination^|findstr Folder1\') do echo %%~tzd >>file.txt`

Comment: As others have stated, your original posted code could not possibly execute. I edited the code to put the entire FOR command on one line, so that it can execute.

Comment: @SomethingDark - I was baffled at first as well. But it works fine. FINDSTR within IN() clause is reading from stdin. Each side of the pipe executes within a new cmd.exe process. The output of the left is piped into the right side cmd.exe process, where FINDSTR is able to read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%%~td` expands to the last modified date/time of the the file, and `%~zd` the size of the file. But only if file `%%d` exists. If the file does not exist, then `%%~td` and `%%~zd` expand to nothing. And `echo` with only whitespace following gives the `ECHO is off.` message.

Your FOR /F tokens and delims options have mangled the original full path of the file - `%%d` does not contain the full path, so the command cannot locate the file.

You need to set `"delims="` to preserve the entire path, and then you only get one token. Everything should then work as you expect:

```
dir /b /s C:\Path\to\the\destiation | for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr Folder1\') do @echo %%~ta  %%~za  %%a >> file.txt
```

If you really must parse the path like you did (it looks screwy to me, but maybe it is useful), then you need a nested inner loop. Your unusual pipe into a FOR statement then becomes overly complicated - better to put the pipe within the IN() clause.

```
for /f "delims=" %%F in (
  'dir /b /s C:\Path\to\the\destiation ^| findstr Folder1\'
) do for /f "delims=\; tokens=3,4,5*" %%a in ("%%F") do echo %%~tF  %%~zF  %%b: %%d >> file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question, but maybe the `tree`command can be useful to you:

```
tree C:\Users\%username%\ > ThisUserContents.txt
```

Comment: He's trying to parse output. The actual outputting works fine.

Comment: What parts of the question is unclear? I'd like to fix it. Where does it become unclear?

Comment: @Neal : This looks like what is termed on SO an "X-Y problem" - you don't state (clearly) what the actual **problem** to be solved is, instead showing us a **solution** that doesn't work. A clear statement of the original problem (with examples) wil normally produce a faster and less frustrating result, since we don't waste time working out what you are trying (and evidently failing) to do.

Answer (score 0):

[Piping `dir` output to a `for /F` loop is correct](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) but

> When a command is piped with `| batch_command` this will instantiate a
>   new `CMD.exe` instance, in effect running:
>
> ```
> C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C /S /D "batch_command"
> ```
>
> This has several side effects …

… e.g. would cause problems with `ECHO ON`/`ECHO OFF` state in this new `CMD.exe` instance.

Moreover, unlike `Powershell` (where *objects* are handled), commands in `cmd` handle ***strings***. Those strings could be interpreted as *paths to files*, for instance when used as [parameter extensions `%%~zd` or `%%~td` etc.](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) in a `for …` loop.

You need nested loops, next code snippet could work for you:

```
for /F "delims=" %%G in ('
      dir /b /s C:\Path\to\the\destiation ^| findstr folder\') do (
  rem debug echo %%G : %%~tG : %%~zG
  for /f "delims=\ tokens=3,4,5*" %%a in ( "%%~G" ) do echo %%b: %%d : %%~tG : %%~zG 
)
```

(Output redirection omitted). Please note that above fixed `tokens=3,4,5*` would fail for folder structure of variable or unequal depth.